# How to get Bash version in .inputrc

Tags: bash, readline

I'm trying to set a `keymap` in my `.inputrc` file, but I want it to be set/executed only when I'm running a bash version >= 4.3 since I'm working on different machines with different bash versions.

Currently my .inputrc has:

```
set editing-mode vi

$if mode=vi 
    set keymap vi-insert
    "jk":vi-movement-mode
$endif
```

and I need something like this:

```
$if ( bash-version >= 4.3 )
   $if mode=vi 
      set keymap vi-insert
      "jk":vi-movement-mode
   $endif
$endif
```

Note:
One of the machines doesn't run bash directly, KSH is run first instead and then bash is `exec bash` from `.kshrc`. Not sure if that makes a difference though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set these `readline` settings in your `.bashrc` using the `bind` command. For example:

```
set -o vi

major=${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}
minor=${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}
if (( major > 4 )) || (( major == 4 && minor >= 3 )); then
    bind -m vi-insert '"jk": vi-movement-mode'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks!...I didn't know you can set `readline` settings from .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

The `$BASH_VERSINFO` environment variable is what you're looking for. It's an array with the values for the version information. However, it looks like readline only supports [checking the name of the calling program](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC11). You might want to just check the [readline library version](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC28). That way it does not matter what program is running it, if it has a compatible readline, it will get your binding.